# Elasticsearch - how to group by and count matches in an index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an instance of Elasticsearch running with thousands of documents. My index has 2 fields like this:

> |____Type_____|__ Date_added __ |
>
> | walking     | 2018-11-27T00:00:00.000 |
>
> | walking     | 2018-11-26T00:00:00.000 |
>
> | running     | 2018-11-24T00:00:00.000 |
>
> | running     | 2018-11-25T00:00:00.000 |
>
> | walking     | 2018-11-27T04:00:00.000 |

I want to group by and count how many matches were found for the "type" field, in a certain range.
In SQL I would do something like this:

```
 select type,  
        count(type)
 from index
 where date_added between '2018-11-20' and '2018-11-30'
 group by type
```

I want to get something like this:

> |   type   |  count   |
>
> | running | 2 |
>
> | walking | 3 |

I'm using the High Level Rest Client api in my project, so far my query looks like this, it's only filtering by the start and end time:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders
                            .rangeQuery("date_added")
                                .from(start.getTime())
                                .to(end.getTime()))
                        )
                    );
```

How can I do a "group by" in the "type" field? Is it possible to do this in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good start! Now you need to add a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/curret/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to your query:

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders
                        .rangeQuery("date_added")
                            .from(start.getTime())
                            .to(end.getTime()))
                    )
                   );

// add these two lines
TermsAggregationBuilder groupBy = AggregationBuilders.terms("byType").field("type.keyword");
sourceBuilder.aggregation(groupBy);
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception on the query. [Here's my query and the exception I'm getting](https://pastebin.com/Z6eYG5sM), I tried adding the termsAggregationBuilder as you suggested, that's what gave me this exception :(

Comment: Ok, try with `type.keyword` instead of `type` as the field name. I've updated my answer

Comment: That was it. It gave If I understood correctly, grouping by text is not enabled by default because it consumes too much memory, so instead we should always have a field with keyword type, right? What is the reasons for the ".keyword"?
[(The result, as expected, thanks a lot)](https://pastebin.com/wQuHgaQi)

Comment: Yes, it is always best to perform aggregating and sorting on keyword fields instead of text field. `type` is of type `text` while `type.keyword` is of type `keyword`

Comment: Hello Val, sorry to bother you again, but I couldn't find it anywhere on the web and didn't want to open another question here. How can I get the results of the aggregation in java? 
I wanted a list/something like: "type1 = count; type2 = count..."

I tried doing "searchResponse.getAggregations().getList();" but it doesn't give me anything close to that. Is it possible in java?

Comment: have you tried `searchResponse.getAggregations().get("byType").getBuckets()` ?

Comment: It seems like I don't have a ".getBuckets()" method, does that belong to an elasticsearch library?

Comment: Try this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response-aggs

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, but it's not working out for me so far..
The searchResponse is just what I expected, but I'm struggling to retrieve the bucket with the types and doc_count from the json in an easy way with elasticsearch methods. I'll open up another question in here soon..

Comment: Ok, make sure to specify which version of ES and the REST client you're running

Comment: I finally got it, I'll answer my own post with better formatting in a few minutes and will let you know. thank you very much Val :D

Answer (score 0):

After using [Val's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501038/5033494) to aggregate the fields, I wanted to print the aggregations of my query together with the value of them. Here's what I did:

```
Terms  terms = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("byType");
Collection<Terms.Bucket> buckets = (Collection<Bucket>) terms.getBuckets();
    for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
        System.out.println("Type: " + bucket.getKeyAsString() + " = Count("+bucket.getDocCount()+")");
    }
```

This is the output after running the query in an index with 2700 documents with a field called "type" and 2 different types:

```
Type: walking = Count(900)
Type: running = Count(1800)
```